# Django request.breadcrumb wont show if the path has given as '#'

Tags: django

```
request.breadcrumbs((
    ('Home', '#'),
    ('BedRoom', request.path_info),
    ('desk', '#')
    ))
```

The code above shows the breadcrumb hierarchy that um planning to use If I omit request.pathinfo it wont show after first leven Ex : - Home > BedRoom > 
I think I have miss something.

Comment: What is `request.breadcrumbs`? You're presumably using some sort of package to create breadcrumbs from this attribute: which one? And does the documentation say you can use `#`?

Comment: Yep my mistake, Ill go through and fix it :) Thank you, and yep we can use '#'